# python virtualenvwrapper refuses to work after upgrade to python3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Keep getting this error when my bashrc is sourced:

```
/usr/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

I have read other posts about this. Most posts state to `pip3 install virtualenwrapper`. This does not work.

I am using a symbolic link for /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3.10.
If I put the link back to /usr/bin/python3.8 it works.

Why wont virtualenvwrapper not work with my /usr/bin/python symbolic link to 3.10?

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` is a collection of shell functions to include into shell. But there have to be a `virtualenvwrapper` python module installed into `site-packages`. You have to install it into the same python:

```
/usr/bin/python3.10 -m pip install virtualenwrapper
```